# Error on Entity Framework .Add() that isn't making any sense

Tags: entity-framework-4.3

I am getting the following error:

> InnerException: {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'database.dbo.bp_UserDetails'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated."}

The problem is that `UserId` *has* a value of 12.

My table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bp_UserDetails](
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL.
    // Other fields
CONSTRAINT [PK_bp_UserDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[UserId] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My model:

```
[Table("bp_UserDetails")]
public class UserDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Customer name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas why I may be getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `DatabaseGeneratedOption` to `None` for the key property in your model:

```cs
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

If you don't do this EF assumes by default that the `UserId` is generated in the database as an identity column and never sends the value to the server.

Comment: Ah... yes, it is a the same key as a primary table. I'll try that.